# pdo_mysql.so problem when try to install composer

Tags: php, composer

I want to install composer by `apt install` or `composer-setup.php`.

After composer made the setup, and says `composer -V` I am getting this error message.

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so'
> (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so
> (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol:
> pdo_parse_params), /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so.so
> (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object
> file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

The file is there.

> ls /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so
> /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so

My sites works on localhost, sql running, what could be wrong?

I've tried purge and reinstall the `php8.1-mysql` but does not helps.

It also happens with any command by php, like `php -i`. It runs, but I am getting this error.

**EDIT:**

I've compeletely purged the whole PHP and reinstall, it helps.

Comment: Please add the output of `php -i | grep 20210902`. It should list `/usr/lib/php/20210902` as the extension directory.

Comment: did you read my post? `ls /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so` it is there.

Comment: That wasn't my point. My point was, is that directory getting picked up as the directory for extensions?

Comment: oh man, no that is not a directoy. I've checked the relevant file and there it is. anyway, solved.